# JSF viewscope values not getting displayed in the view properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a managed bean under ViewScope. It has an instance variable inside it.

MetaData object has a inputItem object List.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConBean implements Serializable {

     private MetaData metadata;

     @PostConstruct
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public void init() throws IOException {
       this.metadata = new MetaData ();
     }

     public void proc(){
        List<InputItem> inputs= new ArrayList<InputItem>();
        inputs.add(***** code to populate the inputItem List);
        //after populating, inputs added to the metadata
        metadata.setInputs(inputs);

     }

//getters & setters
}
```

---

in my JSF , input list is populated inside a UI repeat.

```
<div id="inputplaceholder">
<ui:repeat value="#{conBean.metaData.inputs}" var="content">

</ui:repeat>
</div>
```

the div inputplaceholder is periodically updated using a richfaces poll.

```
<a4j:poll id="poll" interval="12000" action="#{conBean.proc}"
                                  execute="@form" render="inputplaceholder"/>
```

---

The problem that I have is even though inputItems are set to the metaData object correctly inside the proc() method, when the view is rendered/partially updated, it doesn't get highlighted in the UI. so partial update takes no effect. I tried moving

this.metadata = new MetaData ();
inside the proc method but had no luck.

any ideas and help is highly appreciated.

thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the partial render really take place? This is impossible. There is namely no JSF component with the ID `inputplaceholder`. You assigned it to a plain HTML `<div>` element. Replace it by a fullworthy JSF component:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="inputplaceholder">
```

Also, since you used a relative ID in the `render` attribute, it will only scan for components in the same parent naming container component. The `<ui:repeat>` is such one, however the component with the desired ID is placed *outside* it. You'd like to use an absolute ID instead. Assuming that it's inside a `<h:form>` with a fixed ID:

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="inputplaceholder">
        ...
```

then you should be referencing it in the `render` attribute as follows

```
render=":myform:inputplaceholder"
```